# How can I load only one module from Angular library instead of all modules

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have generated an angular library and created two modules named Admin and Client in it.
In each module, I have one service.

```
lib
   admin
      admin.service.ts
      amdin.module.ts
   client
      client.service.ts
      client.module.ts
public-api.ts
```

The content of `public-api.ts` is:

```
export * from './lib/admin/admin.module';
export * from './lib/admin/admin.service';

export * from './lib/admin/client.module';
export * from './lib/client/client.service';
```

Then:

```
ng build core
```

This way, if I import `AdminModule` in `AppModule` like the following:

```
import { AdminModlue } from 'core';
```

Why does Angular load `AdminModule` and `ClientModuel` and their services while it must only load `AdminModule`?

If we inspect the Network tab of our browser we will see in the `main.js`.

How can I load only `AdminModule`?

Comment: Why didn't you create a separate library for each of the modules?

Comment: @R. Richards- because I have a lot of section and it's not possible to create one library for each and then some sections are big I want to split them into some modules in their library in order to have perfect performance while loading them

Answer (score 0):

Do not call any component of module in routing module (`app-routing-module.ts`).

Just call via `loadChildren` method. You may also search for *lazy loading*.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to research about lazy loading. With it you could load your app modules when these will be required. But your first goal must be split your app in nice domain driven modules and configure your main routing config to load with `loadChildren`.

Some references:

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/chain-business-logic-domain-events/

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-code-splitting-or-how-to-share-components-between-lazy-modules-432c755e389c

https://blog.bitsrc.io/boost-angulars-performance-by-lazy-loading-your-modules-ca7abd1e2304